# Set spacing of Gtk3 HeaderBar in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, gnome

According to the official documentation (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHeaderBar.html), `GtkHeaderBar` has a spacing property.

To change the subtitle and title properties in python you would use

```
headerbar.set_title()
headerbar.set_subtitle()
```

So it should therefore follow that `spacing()` would also follow the same rules, however I am informed of the following error

```
AttributeError: 'HeaderBar' object has no attribute 'set_spacing'
```

What is the reason for this? I have not been able to find any specific examples, the documentation is the only place that covers its use, and according to it `spacing` is clearly a property of `GtkHeaderBar`

Appreciate any help you can give here

Comment: `headerbar.set_property('spacing', 0)` maybe?

Comment: You may want to give alook to the GTK+ 3 Python bindings documentation instead of the C ones: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set GObject properties directly, each object has a `props` attribute:

```
headerbar.props.spacing = 5
headerbar.props.subtitle = 'Habits of the Algorithmic Mind'
```

I believe this is so that when you mistype a property name it won't silently fail (e.g. `headerbar.spaing = 5`). Although other language bindings for GObject, such as JS and Ruby, treat GObject properties the same as attributes of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are not the same as attributes.
You can set the property with:

```
your_bar.set_property("spacing", 5)
```

Or, you can define the spacing on instantiating the object:

```
your_bar = Gtk.HeaderBar(spacing = 5)
```

(I prefer the latter - you can set a bunch of properties that way, in one single statement)